# Tar a list of files under a sub directory of another directory

Tags: linux, shell, find, xargs

How do I tar a list of files by name **SOME_FILE_NAME** that are under **SUB_FOLDER** of folder **SOME_FOLDER**. I use following command to list the files

```
find <SOME_FOLDER> -name <SUB_FOLDER> -execdir realpath "{}" ';' | xargs -I p find p -name <SOME_FILE_NAME>
```

For example, following command lists 3 files that I want to tar

**Command**:

```
find /logs/ -name app-2018 -execdir realpath "{}" ';' | xargs -I p find p -name stdout
```

**Output**:

```
/logs/app-2018/2/stdout
/logs/app-2018/0/stdout
/logs/app-2018/1/stdout
```

The result should tar above 3 files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `-path` to match a file's full path. You can check both the file name and the directory it's contained in with one check.

```
find /logs/ -path '*/app-2018/*/stdout' -exec tar -cf logs.tar {} +
```